# Enhance Get-ChildItem pipeline data

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell function `Invoke-SqlParser` (using [GSP](http://sqlparser.com/)) that will extract the list of tables and columns in a SQL script.

I'd like to generate a CSV file that contains the source document's path, in addition to the results of the parsing engine:

```
PS > gci '\\path\to\files' -Include *.sql -Recurse | Get-Content -raw | Invoke-SqlParser -Syntax 'oracle' | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File ~\Desktop\Output.csv
```

Desired content of `Output.csv`:

```
File                        Table  Column
----                        -----  ------
\\path\to\files\script0.sql table0 column0
\\path\to\files\script0.sql table1 column1
\\path\to\files\scriptB.sql tableB columnR
\\path\to\files\scriptB.sql tableC columnQ
```

Is there a way to add the content from the `Invoke-SqlParser` function to the pipeline such that it preserves the content from the `Get-ChildItem` Cmdlet?  Or do I need to 'insert' it into the pipeline generated by the parsing engine?

Comment: You say you have a function, couldn't you just modify the function to pass that data through with the normal output (perhaps with a switch)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure of the right way to do that.  Moreover, do I just add the `FullName` property or the entire `FileInfo` instance?  As there is a 'one-to-many' relationship between the script file and the tables and fields in it, how would that be represented?  Maybe `[PsCustomObject]@{File=$FileInfo;TableColumn=@()}`?

Comment: Without seeing the `Invoke-SqlParser` function I wouldn't know how to help you pass the path through.

Comment: [PsSqlParser](https://github.com/craibuc/PsSqlParser).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you linked is not a function, that's a PowerShell module. What you want is a loop, or a function. I think for your purposes a function would work great for you. This function will allow you to pipe file objects to it, and it will perform your Get-Content, and Invoke-SqlParser commands, adding the full file path to the output with the property 'File'.

```
Function Add-SqlParsing{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('Path')]
        [String]$FullName
    )
    Invoke-SqlParser (Get-Content $FullName -Raw) | Add-Member 'File' $FullName
}
```